# I'm getting "Object library not registered" after re-installing vb6. how to fix?

Tags: vb6

I located vb6.olb on a current working machine, but it says version may not be compatible. how do I determine which library is at fault? I've registered all known dependencies with no avail.

Comment: There used to be a small VB6 utility called VBC6.exe for re-registering all the licenses for the VB6 ActiveX files but I don't think it's available online nowadays.

Comment: Follow [this guide](https://www.tertullian.org/rpearse/installing_vb6_on_win10.htm) on how to install VB6 on Windows 10/11 (and even Windows Server). I've done it successfully a couple of times in the past years.

Comment: What pointed you to vb6.olb specifically as a problem?

Answer (score 0):

nothing meaningful. it was referenced.

the PROBLEM is, referenced lib isn't revealed by the message.